# Transaction with expiration time

Tags: transactions, unconfirmed-transactions

Is it possible to give an expiration time to a Bitcoin transaction so that after a definite time, it can no longer be mined?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, bitcoin transactions that stop being valid after a certain point in time are not possible

Comment: Out of curiosity, are there proposed opcodes such as `OP_PUSHTXDATA` from Johnson Lan which allow for an expiration mechanism? There is no timestamp on the transaction, so specifically `OP_PUSHTXDATA` wouldn't allow to construct an expiration mechanism. Instead, this hypothetical op_code that would enable expiration would need the ability to push the header height to the stack ... anything such proposals so far?